# Efficient casting of int to double

Tags: java, casting, int, double

I want to subtract 2 doubles and cast the result to an integer.

```
 d = 1.41384;
 d1 = 1.4133;

 d2 = (d-d1); /// 0.0005399999999

 int i  = (int) ( d2 /0.00001);  // 53
 int i1 = (int) Math.ceil(( d2 /0.00001)); //54
```

Double are not able to represent all values so a subtraction can lead to false values as in the example above. Could it also happen that the value of a subtraction could be slightly bigger than intended? (e.g. 0.00540000000001) 
Math.ceil gives me the correct answer in this case but is there an more elegant way to solve this issue?

Comment: The problem occurred *before* the subtraction...

Comment: Replace `Math.ceil` with `Math.round` so it works in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is more basic than that, even: the value you think is `1.41384` isn't actually that value, but is slightly different.  The subtraction, in this case at least, is likely to have been accurate, though converting it back to a string will have rounded it off somewhat.